# IIS hosted page returns HTTP Error 404 when accessed

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I have copied a running site to my local machine, and set it up with IIS.

For some reason when I try to access the site  have setup in IIS I get an

Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

None of the logs shows an actual error that I can use?

What sort of debug options do I have with an page that is hosted in IIS.

AppData/logs does not seem to give me any indications on why this is the case?

this is regardless whether I access it as http or https.

Comment: "None of the logs shows an actual error that I can use?" is impossible. Any incoming requests are logged in IIS log files, and you can find what exactly is the substatus code for that 404 error (404.0 or 404.3 for example). Only when you know the substatus code you can know what happens and how to fix.

Comment: It is not recommend to copy site to another IIS, webdeploy is a better choice to migrate site. Then please check IIS log or failed request tracing to check sub status code. Refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code#4xx---client-error) to view the meaning of sub status code. You'd better show the 404 error page and how you access the site.